# It there any default asynchronious null context manager in python3.7+?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, python-3.7

I would like to create optional asynchronious semaphore.
In case of `asyncio.Semaphore` does not support `None` values, i decided to create `asyncio.Semaphore`, if connections limit is specified, else - some kind of dummy object
There is a `contextlib.nullcontext`, but it supports only synchorious `with`
I`ve created my own dummy:

```py
@contextlib.asynccontextmanager
async def asyncnullcontext():
    yield None
```

It there any default asynchronious null context manager?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> It there any default asynchronious null context manager?

You can use [`contextlib.AsyncExitStack()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.AsyncExitStack).

`ExitStack()` was similarly the way to create a quick-and-dirty null context manager before the introduction of `nullcontext`.

Comment: It looks like some kind of misuse, but works exactly as i wanted

Comment: @Trizalio I think misuse is too strong a word, but I agree that it's a bit cryptic. Fun fact: I was the one to [originally propose](https://bugs.python.org/issue10049) adding a null context manager to the standard library almost ten years ago. It took 7 years and persuasion by a number of different people for it to actually make it in. Maybe you'd have better luck with an `asyncnullcontext`? :)

Comment: @Trizalio It appears that `nullcontext` will support `async with` in python 3.10, FYI. See [this bug](https://bugs.python.org/issue41543). @user4815162342 I guess things are moving a little more quickly these days :)

Answer (score 4):

Starting from Python 3.10+, [`contextlib.nullcontext()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.nullcontext) can be used as both a synchronous and asynchronous context manager.

```py
from contextlib import nullcontext

def works():
    with nullcontext():
        pass

async def works_too():
    async with nullcontext():
        pass
```

(This question explicitly mentions Python 3.7 but I guess more and more people may find it without specifically needing that version, hence this answer)